# How can I make substitutions only within the scope of certain LaTeX command arguments?

Tags: ruby, regex, perl, latex

The below Latex is written in one line, but it could have been over several.

The problem is `#` in caption commands have to be escaped, so the question is how to do this only within captions?

Or does there exist a Perl/Ruby module that can find the closing `}` in such a complicated case?

> `\caption{\small{Et elliptisk område i planen er afgrænset af en ellipse som er niveaukurven $\mathcal{K }_{0}(f)$ for andengradspolynomiet $f(x,y) = 2\cdot x^{2} + 2\cdot y^{2} + 2\cdot x\cdot y -8\cdot x -10 \cdot y + 13$. Se opgave \ref{exercEllipseLevel}  og  eksempel \href{./20-Keglesnit.pdf#evncount.20.1}{ 20.1} i eNote \ref{tn20}.}} \label{figEllipseLevel}`

Comment: what you need in output

Comment: Replace `#` with `\#` if it is in a caption.

Comment: check the answer

Comment: Count braces, for instance.  Check for `\caption` and once found set a flag.  While the flag is "on", as you read the file: concatenate lines (that's your buffer), and add counts for left and right braces to their totals (for the buffer). Once you get to have an extra `}` you found the closing brace for `\caption`. Run substitution (for `\#`) on that buffer, reset flags/counters.  This uses the fact that you cannot have multiple `\caption` on a line, makes other assumtpions, and likely leaves out details. Try (or make up your own parser of course), and if there is a problem post the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a brute force solution in Ruby, now that you have added the Ruby tag. It is not efficient, but safe and simple.

```
x.split('\caption').each_with_index.map { |str, i|
  next str if i == 0
  indent = 0
  end_caption = str.length
  str.split('').each_with_index do |c, ci|
    if c == '{'
      indent = indent + 1
    elsif c == '}'
      indent = indent - 1
      if (indent == 0)
        end_caption = ci
        break
      end
    end
  end
  str[0..(end_caption)].gsub(/([^\\])#/,'\1\\#')+ str[(end_caption+1)..-1]
}.join(‘\caption')
```

or if you are looking for a one-liner, then

```
x.gsub(/\\caption\{((?:[^{}]+|\{\g<1>\})+)\}/m)  { |xx| Regexp.last_match[0].gsub(/([^\\])#/,’\1\\#’) }
```

All of these of course requires that your Latex file can compile.

For Perl you could consider [`Text::Balanced`](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/Text-Balanced-2.03/lib/Text/Balanced.pm)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in Perl using two substitutions: the first to find the `\caption` elements, end the second to replace all hash symbols `#` within the elements found

It is convenient to use [`Regexp::Common::balanced`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::balanced) to match the required balanced sequence of braces

The output of this program shows the string before and after editing. It's not the best test data as there is only a single instance of a hash symbol, and none outside the `\caption` element, but it does show that it works with the example data

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Regexp::Common 'balanced';

my $latex = <<'END';
\caption{\small{Et elliptisk område i planen er afgrænset af en ellipse som er niveaukurven $\mathcal{K }_{0}(f)$ for andengradspolynomiet $f(x,y) = 2\cdot x^{2} + 2\cdot y^{2} + 2\cdot x\cdot y -8\cdot x -10 \cdot y + 13$. Se opgave \ref{exercEllipseLevel}  og  eksempel \href{./20-Keglesnit.pdf#evncount.20.1}{ 20.1} i eNote \ref{tn20}.}} \label{figEllipseLevel}
END

say $latex;

$latex =~ s{ ( \\caption $RE{balanced}{-parens=>'{}'} ) }{
    $1 =~ s/#/\\#/gr;
}xeg;

say $latex;
```

#### output

```
\caption{\small{Et elliptisk område i planen er afgrænset af en ellipse som er niveaukurven $\mathcal{K }_{0}(f)$ for andengradspolynomiet $f(x,y) = 2\cdot x^{2} + 2\cdot y^{2} + 2\cdot x\cdot y -8\cdot x -10 \cdot y + 13$. Se opgave \ref{exercEllipseLevel}  og  eksempel \href{./20-Keglesnit.pdf#evncount.20.1}{ 20.1} i eNote \ref{tn20}.}} \label{figEllipseLevel}

\caption{\small{Et elliptisk område i planen er afgrænset af en ellipse som er niveaukurven $\mathcal{K }_{0}(f)$ for andengradspolynomiet $f(x,y) = 2\cdot x^{2} + 2\cdot y^{2} + 2\cdot x\cdot y -8\cdot x -10 \cdot y + 13$. Se opgave \ref{exercEllipseLevel}  og  eksempel \href{./20-Keglesnit.pdf\#evncount.20.1}{ 20.1} i eNote \ref{tn20}.}} \label{figEllipseLevel}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Just Try this:

```
my $str = '\caption{\small{Et elliptisk område i planen er afgrænset af en ellipse som er niveaukurven $\mathcal{K
}_{0}(f)$ for andengradspolynomiet $f(x,y) = 2\cdot x^{2} + 2\cdot y^{2} + 2\cdot x\cdot y -8\cdot x -10 
\cdot y + 13$. Se opgave \ref{exercEllipseLevel}  og  eksempel \href{./20-Keglesnit.pdf#evncount.20.1}{
20.1} i eNote \ref{tn20}.}} \label{figEllipseLevel}';
```

> *You can modify this regex (This is what I am using in my live)*

```
my $reg = qw/((?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*)/;

$str=~s/$reg/$1=~s{\#}{\\#}gr; /seg;

print $str;
```

Output:

```
 \caption{\small{Et elliptisk omrσde i planen er afgrµnset af en ellipse som er niveaukurven $\mathcal{K  
 }_{0}(f)$ for andengradspolynomiet $f(x,y) = 2\cdot x^{2} + 2\cdot y^{2} + 2\cdot x\cdot y -8\cdot x -10  
 \cdot y + 13$. Se opgave \ref{exercEllipseLevel}  og  eksempel \href{./20-Keglesnit.pdf\#evncount.20.1}{  
 20.1} i eNote \ref{tn20}.}} \label{figEllipseLevel}
```